# WPF DataTrigger not working On ComboBox?

Tags: wpf, combobox, datatrigger

I've got the following pure XAML:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ComboBox Name="combo" Height="24" Width="60">
        <Border Background="Gray" Padding="20,10">
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=combo, Path=IsDropDownOpen}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=combo, Path=IsDropDownOpen}"></TextBlock>
</DockPanel>
```

I would expect the datatrigger to change the background colour of the `border` object to `red` as soon as the combobox is opened, but instead nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have set the background property directly on the `ComboBox` the trigger is not going to override that value.

This behavior is explained [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You have to set it in the style instead like this:

```
<Border Padding="20,10">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=combo, Path=IsDropDownOpen}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```